# VB.NET Multiple GET methods in WEB API 2

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, rest, asp.net-web-api, routes

I am using WEB API 2 with VB.NET to create a simple REST service, i am completly new to it.

Lets say i have this Controller.

```
<RoutePrefix("api/Login")>
Public Class LoginController
    Inherits ApiController

    <Route("GetTest")>
    Public Function GetTest() As IHttpActionResult
    End Function

    <Route("GetLogin")>
    Public Function GetLogin(ByVal Username As String, ByVal Password As String) As IHttpActionResult
    End Function

End Class
```

And this WebApiConfig

```
Public Sub Register(ByVal config As HttpConfiguration)
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes()

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name:="DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate:="api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults:=New With {.id = RouteParameter.Optional}
    )
End Sub
```

I cant get the function GetLogin working. I try to call this the following:
http://localhost:PORT/api/Login/GetLogin?Username=NAME?Password=PASSWORD

while the function GetTest is working fine:
http://localhost:PORT/api/Login/GetTest

Please can some one help me to understand and guide me on how this should be done. Thanks

Comment: The query string of a URL starts with a `?` but parameters are separated by a `&`, not a `?`. This is how URLs have worked for decades and is nothing to do specifically with .NET, Web API or anything recent.

Comment: Ohh , you are right. Didnt realized that, lol. Thanks for the tip, works like a charm :)